# Storing data into a file for one time and avoid any changes after running the code again

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

### My code

Here I take a name from a user and save it to a file, my purpose is to give that name an index (Out) and save it into a file, so that each time I run the code, I will still have the same name and index(not new values). So how can I do that?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class h_main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    contact[] table = new contact[3]; //Create an object of contact class
    int tablesize = 3;

    // Input from user

    //**Inserting from user**//
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); // Reading from System.in
    System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
    String names = reader.nextLine();       

    // Save the inserted name inside a table array with an index Out(from the hash function)

    int Out = calc_hash(names, tablesize);
    table[Out] = new contact();
    table[Out].Name = names;
    System.out.println(Out);

    // Writing

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
      FileWriter fWriter = null;
      BufferedWriter writer = null;
      try {
        fWriter = new FileWriter("text.txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        writer.write(table[i].Name);
        writer.write(table[i].phone);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
      }
      //   System.err.println("Your input of " + table[i].Name.length + " characters was saved.");
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
      }

      // Reading

      // The name of the file to open.
      String fileName = "text.txt";

      // This will reference one line at a time
      String line = null;

      try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("text.txt");

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println("Name: " + line);
        }

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
          "Unable to open file '" +
          "text.txt" + "'");
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
          "Error reading file '" +
          "text.txt" + "'");
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  //**Generate hash function**//
  public static int calc_hash(String names, int table_size) {
    int i, l = names.length();
    int hash = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {

      hash += Character.getNumericValue(names.charAt(i));
      hash += (hash << 10);
      hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    if (hash > 0) return hash % table_size;
    else return -hash % table_size;
  }
}

Class contact
    public class contact {
    String Name ;
    int phone ; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear and I doubt anyone is going to read all that code to try to figure out what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Have the file not exist when you run the program for the first time. After you do, use the existence of the file to determine whether the program has been run before or not. Your code could look like this:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // It's recommended to follow Java naming and style conventions:
        // Class names always begin with an uppercase letter
        Contact[] table = new Contact[3];
        String fileName = "text.txt";

        Path file = Paths.get(fileName);
        // Check for persistence file:
        if(Files.exists(file)) {
            // If all you need to do is print each line, try this:
            try {
                Files.lines(file).forEach(l -> System.out.println("Name: " + l));
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error reading data file!");             
            }
        } else {
            // Take data input
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            // ...

            // When program is terminated, save everything:     
            try(BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file)) {
                // use writer to write data...
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error writing data file!");
            }
        }

    }

}
```